# Trying to fetch all of the servers that my bot is in

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'listguilds',
    description: 'lists the bots guilds',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        
        const Guilds = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    console.log(Guilds);
    }}
```

Im trying to fetch all the ID's of all of the guilds that my bot is in but i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'guilds' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\commands\listguilds.js:6:31)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\index.js:96:11)
    at Client.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\botname\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

Comment: Where are you trying to read a property `servers`?

Comment: i edited the code, it should be guilds

Comment: `client` is undefined. How are you calling `execute()`?

Comment: Are your parameters provided in the correct order?

Comment: Because that's a common mistake. When you call the `.execute()` function, make sure the parameters are in this order `.execute(message, args, client)`